# Tomcat 7 is unable to display jsp

Tags: java, apache, jsp, servlets, tomcat7

I have created a simple dynamic web project contains a jsp page displays Hello Word with current date and time in Eclipse with tomcat 7.0.22 in my local system. It is showing expected result.

Now I exported the war file and dropped into the ../webapps folder of tomcat in my linux box. when I am opening my application using browser then it is showing the source code.

But if I remove the java coding within the jsp it is diplaying whatever I have written in the  part.

Can you please advise.

Comment: Can you paste the content in your jsp file

Comment: <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

Comment: <%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.*,java.text.*" %>


<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>I am Here</title>

<h1>Welcome Thiru !!</h1>

</head>
<body>

<center>
<h1>Display Current Date & Time</h1>
</center>

<% Date dNow = new Date( );
   SimpleDateFormat ft = 
   new SimpleDateFormat ("E yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh:mm:ss a zzz");
   out.print( "<h2 align=\"center\">" + ft.format(dNow) + "</h2>");
  %>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Might be your Environment set-up issue.
When you run ./start.sh file its show the following details

Using CATALINA_BASE:  path to tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:  path to tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: path to tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:       path of java
Using CLASSPATH:       path to tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jarpath to tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
Check where your getting this details ....???????

Comment: INFO: Starting tomcat-tomcatDev Tomcat Server
Executing script:         /sbcimp/run/pd/apache_tomcat/7.0.23/bin/catalina.sh
Using JRE_HOME:           /sbcimp/run/tp/sun/jre/v1.7.0_51
Using CATALINA_BASE:      /sbcimp/dyn/data/RISK/credit/ctw/Creation/tomcatDev
Using CATALINA_HOME:      /sbcimp/run/pd/apache_tomcat/7.0.23

Comment: Using CATALINA_TMPDIR:    /sbcimp/dyn/data/RISK/credit/ctw/Creation/tomcatDev/tmp
Using CATALINA_PID:       /sbcimp/dyn/data/RISK/credit/ctw/Creation/tomcatDev/tmp/crea1dev_tomcat-tomcatDev.pid
Using JAVA_OPTS:
Using CATALINA_OPTS:      -Xmx64M -Ddev_property_path=/sbcimp/dyn/data/RISK/credit/ctw/Creation/14.08.03/xldn5496vdap/DEV/config/CreationWeb.prop
Using CLASSPATH:          /sbcimp/run/pd/apache_tomcat/7.0.23/bin/bootstrap.jar:/sbcimp/run/pd/apache_tomcat/7.0.23/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using Security Manager

Comment: When I am starting the server I am getting it

Comment: @nayan :JRE_HOME should be the path of just jdk ,as per your details it's pointing to jre......
correct the jdk path

Comment: I dont think it is problem. In the same linux system we are running tomcat 6.0.14 and it is working fine. Here is the startup log :-     INFO: Starting tomcat-tomcat_dev Tomcat Server
Executing script:         /sbcimp/run/pd/apache_tomcat/6.0.14/bin/catalina.sh

Using JRE_HOME:           /sbcimp/run/tp/sun/jre/v1.5.0_11
Using CATALINA_BASE:      /sbcimp/dyn/data/RISK/credit/ctw/Creation/tomcat_dev
Using CATALINA_HOME:      /sbcimp/run/pd/apache_tomcat/6.0.14

Comment: When I am working in local system it is running and compiling on JRE 6 but in linux system our tomcat is running on JDK 1.7. is that the reason why war is not working in linux machine?

Comment: First Line of  web.xml is looks like :-                                          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

Answer (score 0):

You may missed closing tags or JSP expression tags or some syntax error.

Comment: If I missed any jsp tag then how same war file is working in local desktop?

Comment: <%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.*,java.text.*" %>


<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>I am Here</title>

<h1>Welcome Thiru !!</h1>

</head>
<body>

<center>
<h1>Display Current Date & Time</h1>
</center>

<% Date dNow = new Date( );
   SimpleDateFormat ft = 
   new SimpleDateFormat ("E yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh:mm:ss a zzz");
   out.print( "<h2 align=\"center\">" + ft.format(dNow) + "</h2>");
  %>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Check for the exported war file whether required jars are there or not.